# flood fill python, solving a maze

Tags: python-2.7, flood-fill

Returning an index out of range error, someone please help!

```
def floodfill(maze, x, y, a, b):
    #maze[x][y] = b
    for i in range(1,len(maze)):
        for j in range(len(maze[i])):
            if maze[i-1][j] == a or [i][j-1] == a or maze[i-1][j] == b or maze[i][j-1] == b:
                if maze[i][j] == a:
                    maze[i][j] = b
    return maze
```

here is the "maze" being solved.... the flood fill is supposed to change all 0 into 1

```
[[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1], 
 [-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1], 
 [-1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1], 
 [-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1], 
 [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1], 
 [-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1], 
 [-1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1], 
 [-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1], 
 [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In the 5th line of your code, in the first `or`, it just says `[i][j-1]` by itself.

```
>>> i = 9
>>> j = 10
>>> [i][j-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

You are trying to get the `j-1`<sup>th</sup> value of the integer `i`, which clearly does not work :).

Just put `maze` before these two to make this: `maze[i][j-1]`.